# mule 4 Unable to convert CLOB to JSON

Tags: dataweave, mule4

In Mule 4 I am reading a clob column(data is in JSON) from Oracle DB Table and tring to transform to JSON. I am getting a String response with all the escape characters and hence unable to parse JSON. My transformation is as below

```
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="12c74f4a-56d7-4d9a-9cb1-1348c93edfe2" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
```

The output I am getting is as below

```
{"EXPENSE_REPORT_DETAILS": "{\n  \"UserLoginID\": \"xyz\",\n  \"EmployeeName\": \"abcd\"}}
```

Is there any way I can get back JSON instead of String without all the escape characters so I can parse. Even Java would be fine as what I need is to get `payload.EXPENSE_REPORT_DETAILS.UserLoginID` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLOB is just a large string. You just need to look for ways to convert a string to JSON.
Because your string is in `payload.EXPENSE_REPORT_DETAILS` you need to use read function and pass it as the first param

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  EXPENSE_REPORT_DETAILS: read(payload.EXPENSE_REPORT_DETAILS,"application/json")
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this previously and I am getting the below Message  org.mule.runtime.api.el.ExpressionExecutionException: You called the function 'AnonymousFunction' with these arguments: 
  1: Object ({EXPENSE_REPORT_DETAILS: "{\n  \"UserLoginID\": \"xyz\",\n  \"Emplo...)
  2: String ("application/json")

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: String | Binary
  2: String
  3: Object             
Payload Type          : org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.CaseInsensitiveHashMap

Comment: I noticed that in the question later. Your payload is not a CLOB. The `EXPENSE_REPORT_DETAILS` in your payload is a CLOB. So you will need to read that only. (I have updated the same in my answer)