# convert issue -Clob to string in mule

Tags: oracle, api, dataweave, mulesoft

I am unable to find the solution for converting clob to string in mule dataweave ,so it could great if some one look into this and help me to find the solution.

Clob name : Addtional business desc: it has 9k charactters.

this clob need to convert it as string and assign to other attribute in mule transform message.
for ex: Description : payload.Addtional business desc
Current error: closed connection while reading the Addtional business desc as text plain

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using exactly?

Comment: It's Mulesoft 4

Comment: Exact version should be more complete like 4.2.1. What is the version of the database connector? In any case you are not having a conversion issue. The problem is that the connection is closing while the clob is being read. To troubleshoot that issue will require more details of configurations, database, errors and versions

Comment: Please share the solution as an answer to your question so others can reuse it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72519915/mule-4-unable-to-convert-clob-to-json?rq=1

Comment: Proposing to close as duplicate of [mule 4 Unable to convert CLOB to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72519915/mule-4-unable-to-convert-clob-to-json)